# Writing function name as the value of a string variable

Tags: php

I have a string variable

```
$worker_name = "video_convert"
```

I want to write a function with the name like the following

```
function video_convert(){
}
```

How can I do this in PHP? I tried

```
function eval($worker_name){
}
```

or

```
eval($worker_name) = function(){
}
```

But, it seems like it is not the correct way to do it in PHP.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why calling the way you want?

Comment: You want to essentially randomize the names of your functions? This is a bad idea. What for‽

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as

```
$worker_name = 'video_convert';
$$worker_name = function() {
   echo 'hi';
};
$$worker_name();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `call_user_func` :

```
$worker_name ="video_convert"
function video_convert($text){
     echo "Hello $text\n";
}

call_user_func($worker_name, 'World');
```

OR you could use the way you tried:

```
$worker_name = 'video_convert';
function video_convert(){
    echo __METHOD__;
}
$worker_name();
```

OR like this:

```
$worker_name = function($text)
{
    echo 'Anonymous function call '.$text
};

$worker_name('Hello');
```

PHP is flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do somewhat like as

```
$worker_name = "video_convert";

function video_convert(){
    echo "I've called a function using variable";
}

$worker_name();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use eval() function then use it by below way:-

```
$worker_name = "video_convert()";

function video_convert(){
    echo "Called";
}

eval("$worker_name;");
```